# Multiple case validation using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have created the following login form in html and validation has been done using jquery validate plugin.
http://jqueryvalidation.org/
Here , I am validating the whole login form when the login button is clicked.

```
    <form method="POST" id="LoginForm">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_Email" name="user_Email" />
        <br>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="user_Pass" name="user_Pass" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="btnLogin">
    </form>
```

**validation script**

```
$("#LoginForm").validate({
    rules: {
        user_Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        user_Pass: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user_Email: {
            required: "Email is required",
            email: "Enter a valid email address"
        },
        user_Pass: {
            required: "Password is required"
        }
    }
});
$('#btnLogin').click(function() {
    var form = $('#LoginForm');
    if (form.valid()) {
        // submit the form data
    }
});
```

Like validating the whole form with error labels when the button is clicked , I also want to validate only the email field without error labels and error classes for another case. 
When user entering a email address i want to validate the validity of the email address(true or false) without validating the whole form and without displaying the error label.Just the validity.
How to achieve this using jquery validation plugin. I tried it jquery input text change event, but it does not work.

```
$('#user_Email').on('input',function(){
    //check for a valid email address on text change of email input
})
```

Please help me in this. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to use this plugin to do a validity test without also triggering validation messages.   The question is also unclear.  **Why** would you need to do this?  Either the data is valid or it isn't... what's the point of not notifying the user?

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
$( "#user_Email" ).focusout(function() {
  var re    = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  var email = $("#user_Email").val();
  if(!re.test(email)) {
      //give proper valodation message here
      alert("Invalid Email...!!");
      $("#user_Email").focus();
      }
});
```

This will show alert message when invalid email addess is given andd pass to next next field and cursor will back in email field

**EDIT**

As  per your comment the validation with http://jqueryvalidation.org/
 for one single field (email) is shown below.

```
  $('#btnLogin').click(function() {
        if($("#LoginForm").validate().element($("#user_Email"))){
        //give proper valodation message here
        alert("Invalid Email..!!");
        }
    });
```

Enjoy coding... :)

Comment: yep this is correct. but is there any way to achieve this using jquery validation plugin. Lets assume that i have a form with 10 fields and i want to validate first 5 fields on one button click and last 5 fields in another button click using jquery validate ???

Comment: Check out the edited code and add to your code .. enjoy the coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this small & simple plugin

http://suraj-mahajan.github.io/Validate-In-Grid-Controls/